# php7.4 mysqli times out with "gone away"

Tags: php, mysql, php-7.4

I have just installed php7.4, everything seems ok but when I try to go on my phpmyadmin, I can't :
Note works fine in php7.3 before this installation

The error is :

```
mysqli_real_connect(): Unexpected server response while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away
```

looking my php mysql library :`php7.4-mysql`. it's installed.

Forget something ?
Thank you.

```
NOTICE: Not enabling PHP 7.4 FPM by default.
NOTICE: To enable PHP 7.4 FPM in Apache2 do:
NOTICE: a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
NOTICE: a2enconf php7.4-fpm
NOTICE: You are seeing this message because you have apache2 package installed.
Traitement des actions différées (« triggers ») pour libapache2-mod-php7.4 (7.4.
0-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1) ...

apt-cache policy php7.4
php7.4:
  Installé : 7.4.0-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1
  Candidat : 7.4.0-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1
 Table de version :
 *** 7.4.0-1+ubuntu19.10.1+deb.sury.org+1 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu eoan/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Did you do what the Notices suggested

Comment: Yes, I do that.

Comment: Note : with phpstorm, I see my database. The connexion works

Comment: I saw this error in log : MySQL server has gone away

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, but using `mysql_native_password` was not possible with `PHP7.4-mysql-pdo`, even on setting in `my.cnf` as it worked on `PHP7.3-mysql-pdo`.

I had to alter **every user** with this query:

```
ALTER USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'password';
```

where `username` is the database username and `password` is the password of the database user.

Answer (score 2):

If you still use the dated `mysql_native_password` method, which is **HIGHLY DISCOURAGED** as it is considered less secure, you could set the default authentication plug-in to native password by adding `default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password` to the `[mysqld]` section of **my.cnf**.

Answer (score 1):

In file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

After `[mysqld]` add:
`default-authentication-plugin = mysql_native_password`

Example of my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
[mysqld]
user   = mysql
pid-file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket   = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port   = 3306
basedir    = /usr
datadir    = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir   = /tmp
lc-messages-dir  = /usr/share/mysql
log-error    = /var/log/mysql/error.log
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

bind-address = 0.0.0.0

# PHP 7.4 Fix
default-authentication-plugin = mysql_native_password

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode = "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
```

And remember use mysql_native_password not good because of security.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the encryption of the password like this.

```
ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'youpassword';
```