# Does mysqli have support for caching_sha2_password in PHP 7.4?

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, mysqli, php-7.4

When I tried upgrading from PHP 7.3 to PHP 7.4, I received this error:

> Unexpected server response while doing caching_sha2 auth 109

As I see it, this indicates that PHP 7.4 MySQLi is trying to use the `caching_sha2_password` plugin. [This article](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.requirements.php) points out that PHP MySQLi does not support the plugin (it also hints future support for it), but since PHP 7.4 is new and seems to be trying to use it, I guess it should work. Also the error message is different, than if it wasn't supported (*access denied* vs. *authentication method unknown*).

So I changed my MySQL authentication plugin to `caching_sha2_password` (using the same password as before):

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY '';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But this caused another error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES).

Switching back to PHP 7.3 and `mysql_native_password` it works again.

I used the same password for both plugins, the same website and applied the same php.ini changes.
I however did not change any `mysqli` configuration. The logs for MySQL show nothing, the apache2 log only shows the 'Access Denied' error message.

Does php7.4-mysqli have support for `caching_sha2_password`? **YES**

**Why is my password being denied and how can I fix it?** [See my follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432704/php-7-4-mysql-caching-sha2-password-randomly-denying-passwords)

<strike>Also, if MySQLi still doesn't support the plugin: How can I use `mysql_native_password` with it?</strike>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tested this, and mysqli in PHP 7.4 does support the caching_sha2_password.

```
php -v
PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Nov 29 2019 16:18:44) ( NTS )
```

Here's a simple PHP script I wrote to connect to MySQL 8.0.17 running in a docker container (using port 6603):

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$conn = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', 'root', '', 6603);
$result = $conn->query("SELECT NOW()");
$now = $result->fetch_row()[0];
echo "$now\n";
```

I confirmed that my MySQL instance is using caching_sha2_password:

```
mysql> select user,host,plugin from mysql.user where user='root';
+------+-----------+-----------------------+
| user | host      | plugin                |
+------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root | %         | caching_sha2_password |
| root | localhost | caching_sha2_password |
+------+-----------+-----------------------+

mysql> select @@default_authentication_plugin;
+---------------------------------+
| @@default_authentication_plugin |
+---------------------------------+
| caching_sha2_password           |
+---------------------------------+
```

Running my PHP script, it was successful.

```
php my.php
2019-12-08 18:11:58
```

However, when I tried to change the password to `''` like you did, I was able to reproduce the same error:

> PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): Unexpected server response while doing caching_sha2 auth: 0 in /Users/bkarwin/Documents/SO/my.php on line 5

When I restored the password, setting it to a non-blank string, it fixed the issue.

Don't use blank passwords.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't use a blank password (sry, should have made that clearer). But knowing that it can work already helps. I'll try again, see if I can avoid `Access Denied` and then come back to you.

Comment: You set a blank password with `ALTER USER ... BY ''`. When I tried the same thing, it set a blank password.

Comment: `... BY '';` was just the shortend version, I actually entered `... BY 'mySecretPassword';`

Comment: I tried again, and I still have the same issue `Access Denied` eventhough I literally copy the password over. My PHP was actually build one day before yours: `PHP 7.4.0 (cli) (built: Nov 28 2019 07:27:06) ( NTS )` maybe it's just a bug?

Comment: I can't reproduce that, so I don't know. I really hope the _same_ PHP version compiled one day apart doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you use `mysqlnd` or `mysql_client`? (see Machavity's answer)

Comment: `php -i` tells me it's mysqlnd.

Comment: Would be nice, if you could check out [my follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432704/php-7-4-mysql-caching-sha2-password-randomly-denying-passwords).

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of ways this could happen

1. You're using the `mysql_client` method of authentication. This is how PHP used to do it natively, by connecting to MySQL through the MySQL CLI interface. MySQL's own client will always support its own authentication methods.
2. You're using MySQLND under 7.4. Apparently [this was an improvement to the native driver](https://github.com/php/php-src/commit/4f06e67ad2201390ed35a9ea6288a00c0b04782b#commitcomment-32356655) that went unannounced

   > Yes, this is only in 7.4 right now, due to the hard dependency on ext/hash.

   [There are still some possible issues with it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59120368/php7-4-mysqli-times-out-with-gone-away)

Comment: What really confuses me, is that everything works fine on the transmission part,but my password gets denied. Eventhough I literally copy paste it for `mysql_native_password` and `caching_sha2_password` and only the first one works.

Comment: Do you know how to switch between native driver and mysql client?

Comment: Depends how your server is set up. The [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.library.choosing.php) goes over some of the common setups.

Comment: Thanks, I am using `mysqlnd`, which might be the issue here so I guess I'll wait for full support.

Comment: Would be nice, if you could check out [my follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59432704/php-7-4-mysql-caching-sha2-password-randomly-denying-passwords).